# Use a generic type argument in code at runtime

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to use a generic type argument inside the function block:

Pseudocode:

```
type MyType = number | string

function myFunction<T extends MyTpe>(arg1: any, arg2: any,..): <T> {
  if (T === number) { // do this }
  if (T === string) { // do that }
}
```

Is that possible at all or do I need to provide that as an actual argument to that function to be able to match on this?

Comment: That is not possible. All this type information is not available at runtime.